# Missing a using directive

Tags: c#, directive, using

Brand new to C# and trying to write a test program.
However, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeTests.cs(30,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'book'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>   [C:\dev\gradebook\test\GradeBook.tests\GradeBook.tests.csproj]
>   TypeTests.cs(45,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'book'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>   [C:\dev\gradebook\test\GradeBook.tests\GradeBook.tests.csproj]
>   TypeTests.cs(86,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'book'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>   [C:\dev\gradebook\test\GradeBook.tests\GradeBook.tests.csproj]

tried a rebuild and re-adding xunit

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace GradeBook.tests
{
    public class TypeTests
    {
         [Fact]
         public void Test1() 
         {
             var x = GetInt();

             Assert.Equal(3, x);
         }

         private int GetInt() 
         {
             return 3;
         }

         [Fact]
        public void CSharpCanPassByRef()
        {
            var book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
            GetBookSetName(ref book1, "New Name");

            Assert.Equal("Book 1", book1.name);

        }
        private void GetBookSetName(ref Book book, string name) 
        {
            book = new Book(name); 
        }

         [Fact]
        public void CSharpIsPassByValue()
        {
            var book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
            GetBookSetName(book1, "New Name");

            Assert.Equal("Book 1", book1.name);

        }

        private void GetBookSetName(Book book, string name) 
        {
            book = new Book(name);

        }
        [Fact]
        public void CanSetNameFromReference()
        {
            var book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
            SetName(book1, "New Name");

            Assert.Equal("New Name", book1.name);

            }

        private void SetName(BookTests book, string name) 
        {
            book.Name = name;
        }
        [Fact]
        public void GetBookReturnDifferentObject() 
        {
            var book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
            var book2 = GetBook("Book 2");

            Assert.Equal("Book1", book1.name);
            Assert.Equal("Book2", book2.name);
            Assert.NotSame(book1, book2);
        }


        [Fact]
        public void TwoVarsCanReferenceSameObject()
        {
            var book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
            var book2 = book1;

            Assert.Same(book1, book2);
            Assert.True(Object.ReferenceEquals(book1, book2));
        }

        Book GetBook(string name) 
        {
            return new Book(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use a class called `Book`.  Where do you define it?  (Though it's worth noting that your error messages use the *lowercase* name `book`, not the class name `Book`.  Is this a mistake on your part?  It's important to be specific.)

Comment: That is an error you'll see if the type (class/struct) isn't defined. As @David alluded to, .NET code typically uses pascal case for type names and namespaces, so I'd recommend your namespace be `GradeBook.Tests` (so you'd probably want to have done that on creation of this project) and use `class Book` when you define it. Weird that the error is looking for lowercase `book` when your example code only uses `new Book`...

Comment: To define your missing `Book` class, you could do it in the same file within the namespace declaration, or another file. If in another file, if it's in the same namespace your Test class will automatically be able to see it, else you'll need to add a `using` to reference the other namespace. Welcome to C#!

Comment: Hi David,
book is defined in the program:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GradeBook
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

          var book = new Book("Joe's Gradebook");
          book.AddGrade(89.1);
          book.AddGrade(90.5);
          book.AddGrade(77.5);
          book.GetStatistics(); }}}
I set a reference between the test and the main program.

Comment: That is not the definition of `Book`, that's the instantiation of an object of type `Book`. In what namespace is the class `Book` defined? You need to add a `using NameSpaceOfBook;` directive in the other files where you reference it.

Comment: Thought it might be helpful to see once I rectified the casing on book:
TypeTests.cs(32,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Book' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\dev\gradebook\test\GradeBook.tests\GradeBook.tests.csproj]

Comment: Book is defined:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GradeBook
{

    public class Book
    {
        public Book(string name)
        {
            grades = new List<double>();
            Name = name;

Comment: Since it's a compiler error, you should see red lines under the faulty code. If you hover the cursor above the highlighted text, you should see a light bulb (in Visual Studio). Click on it and look at the suggestion. You can automatically add the missing `using`. My previous comment is still valid, though.

Comment: That was my thinking but I'm getting no lines or light bulbs :(

Comment: Switched to Visual Studio 2019 and that threw some errors that I could fix!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you need referencing your project

1. add **dotnet add reference**  at your terminal

Example

```
dotnet add reference <PROJECT> ..\..\src\GradeBook\GradeBook.csproj
```

2. check your cs file and see the namespace that creating class `public class Book`
3. If the namespace using `GradeBook` then your `namespace GradeBook.tests` need to change into `namespace GradeBook`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I changed from namespace GradeBook.Tests to namespace Gradebook